# Бинарное отрицание ~a

Tags: java

Кто-нибудь может объяснить (мне :) ), почему строчки

```
int a = 1010;
int b = ~a;
System.out.println(" int a = " + a);
System.out.println(" int ~a = " + b);
```

Дают результат

```
      int ~a = -1011
```

А не ожидаемый мной результат

```
   int ~a = 0101
```

?

Comment: `int a = 1010;` а кто сказал, что это двоичная форма?

Comment: двоичная запись int a = 0b1010, а у вас десятичная

Comment: Даже если в двоичной форме запишите, все равно не получите ожидаемого результата, т.к. знаковый бит также инвертируется и вы получите отрицательное число минус 1. Т.е. в вашем случае это будет -11.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку `0b1010` 32-битное, то оно на самом деле равно

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010
```

и его отрицание есть

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110101
```

Но у вас, как првильно замечено, даже не `0b1010`.